# Why is the process's StandardOutput only receiving data after the process has been terminated?

Tags: c#

```
using (var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = {
        FileName = "net.exe",
        Arguments = @"use \\127.0.0.1\abc /user:test",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    }
})
{
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Data);
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Data);
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    string line;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "stop") process.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);
    process.Close();
}
```

When you run this command in cmd it will ask you for a password, However, when i execute the same command like that i don't receive any output until the process is terminated. It doesn't even wait for me to enter the password.
Is something wrong with the code? Am i misunderstanding something?
It also bugs with some other processes like systeminfo.exe.

Note: I'm not building this just to use the 'net use' command, This is just a test application to try some things until this problem is fixed.

Comment: May not be your current issue but you should be aware that some programs will re-open the console for I/O purposes when prompting for passwords - which means redirection doesn't work for them. So even if this does work for `net use`, it may fail completely once the real program is substituted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the output of a process is buffered internally, its behavior may change in a subtle way depending on the destination of the output. If the output is console, writing an end-of-line character automatically flushes the output buffer. When the output is a file or some other stream (e.g. another program that tries to read its output) the printouts may remain buffered until one of three things happen:

1. The program writes enough output to make the buffer flush automatically, or
2. The program flushes the buffer explicitly, or
3. The program exits.

It appears that you are observing case number three.